# x86_64 incorrect calling convention when calling function

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-codegen

I'm relatively new to LLVM, and I'm attempting to generate LLVM IR that calls a C function (`growDictionary`). This is on x86_64 Linux, using llvm 12:

```
$ llc-12 --version
Ubuntu LLVM version 12.0.1

  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: broadwell
```

The function (defined in C++ as `extern "C"`, compiled with clang 12):

```
struct StringDictionary {
    uint32_t* base;
    uint32_t elementSize;
    uint32_t rowCount;
    uint32_t wordsCapacity;
};

extern "C" {
StringDictionary growStringDictionary(StringDictionary dict,
                                      uint32_t neededWordsCapacity);
}
```

The function takes the StringDictionary object by value, but, according to the x86_64 ABI (https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf, section 3.2.3, "Parameter Passing") should have it passed on the stack. (The object's size is greater than 2 eightbytes and neither of the eightbytes is in class SSE or SSEUP, so it turns into class MEMORY according to the "post merger cleanup" section.) A cursory look at the disassembly confirms that this is indeed the case:

```
Dump of assembler code for function growStringDictionary(rockset::jit::StringDictionary, uint32_t):
   0x00007ffff7f98f70 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00007ffff7f98f71 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00007ffff7f98f74 <+4>: push   %rbx
   0x00007ffff7f98f75 <+5>: and    $0xffffffffffffffe0,%rsp
   0x00007ffff7f98f79 <+9>: sub    $0x1c0,%rsp
   0x00007ffff7f98f80 <+16>:    mov    %rsp,%rbx
   0x00007ffff7f98f83 <+19>:    mov    %esi,0x15c(%rbx)
   0x00007ffff7f98f89 <+25>:    mov    %rdi,0x160(%rbx)
[...]
```

`%rdi` is the address where the return value will be written, `%esi` is the uint32_t neededWordsCapacity argument, no other argument passing registers are used.

This is all fine so far, but I'm now trying to call this function from my generated IR, and it tries to pass all arguments in registers. Here are the relevant sections of code:

```
  %83 = call { i32*, i32, i32, i32 } @growStringDictionary({ i32*, i32, i32, i32 } %70, i32 %73)
[...]
declare { i32*, i32, i32, i32 } @growStringDictionary({ i32*, i32, i32, i32 }, i32)
```

Note that the calling convention is default (not changed to something like fastcc).

The generated code (both the JIT I'm trying to use and llc produce the same result) os trying to pass the argument in registers, here's the output from `llc -O0`; `-O3` is similar:

```
        movl    148(%rsp), %r9d                 # 4-byte Reload
        movl    140(%rsp), %r8d                 # 4-byte Reload
        movl    136(%rsp), %ecx                 # 4-byte Reload
        movl    132(%rsp), %edx                 # 4-byte Reload
        movq    120(%rsp), %rsi                 # 8-byte Reload
        leaq    376(%rsp), %rdi
        callq   growStringDictionary@PLT
```

Unsurprisingly, my code segfaults.

I'm surprised that llc generated code that doesn't match the ABI. Are there any attributes I need to put on the function declaration, or on the type definition, or is there anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: The same behavior occurs if I use an identified type instead of a literal type.

Comment: I don't think you are reading the parameter restrictions correctly.   The text, somewhat awkwardly, P21@2 `If the size of an object is larger than eight eightbytes, or it contains un- aligned fields, it has class MEMORY`.   Looking at that code burst: `%rdi = addr of retval; %rsi  = dict.base; %edx = dict.e9e; %ecx = dict.rowbase; %r8 = dict.w11y; %r9 = m17y`.

Comment: It may be that I'm misunderstanding, but P22@5 says "If the size of the aggregate exceeds two eightbytes and the first eightbyte isn’t SSE or any other eightbyte isn’t SSEUP, the whole argument is passed in memory."

Comment: Indeed, if > 16 bytes, passed on the stack: https://godbolt.org/z/WYoabjsxd

Comment: Something is messed up, but clang and gcc are consistent with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this part of the calling convention is handled by the frontend (together with, I presume, things like "this is a non-trivial C++ object").

Take this example file:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct A {
  uint32_t* p;
  uint32_t a;
  uint32_t b;
};

struct B {
  uint32_t* p;
  uint32_t a;
  uint32_t b;
  uint32_t c;
};

uint32_t addA(struct A x) {
  return x.a + x.b;
}

uint32_t addB(struct B x) {
  return x.a + x.b + x.c;
}
```

`clang -S -emit-llvm` says:

```
%struct.A = type { i32*, i32, i32 }
%struct.B = type { i32*, i32, i32, i32 }

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define dso_local i32 @addA(i32* %0, i64 %1) #0 {
  %3 = alloca %struct.A, align 8
  %4 = bitcast %struct.A* %3 to { i32*, i64 }*
  %5 = getelementptr inbounds { i32*, i64 }, { i32*, i64 }* %4, i32 0, i32 0
  store i32* %0, i32** %5, align 8
  %6 = getelementptr inbounds { i32*, i64 }, { i32*, i64 }* %4, i32 0, i32 1
  store i64 %1, i64* %6, align 8
  %7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %3, i32 0, i32 1
  %8 = load i32, i32* %7, align 8
  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %3, i32 0, i32 2
  %10 = load i32, i32* %9, align 4
  %11 = add i32 %8, %10
  ret i32 %11
}

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define dso_local i32 @addB(%struct.B* byval(%struct.B) align 8 %0) #0 {
  %2 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.B, %struct.B* %0, i32 0, i32 1
  %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 8
  %4 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.B, %struct.B* %0, i32 0, i32 2
  %5 = load i32, i32* %4, align 4
  %6 = add i32 %3, %5
  %7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.B, %struct.B* %0, i32 0, i32 3
  %8 = load i32, i32* %7, align 8
  %9 = add i32 %6, %8
  ret i32 %9
}
```

Note that the argument to `addB` has become `%struct.B* byval(%struct.B)` indicating that this is passed on the stack.